# What is the intended purpose of a login shell?

Tags: bash, login

Bash manual says:

> A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is‘ -’, or one invoked with the --login option.

It defines a login shell in terms of the ways to start a login shell.

Alternatively, can a login shell be defined in terms of its intended purpose?

For example, can a login shell be defined as a shell which requires user to log in?
For example, in an interactive nonlogin bash shell, when I run `bash --login` to create a bash login shell, I don't have to log in. Is it because my username and password are cached and reused implicitly, or simply it doesn't perform the job of login?

If a login shell doesn't necessarily have to perform log in, what is its intended purpose that can characterize a login shell from a nonlogin shell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Login is handled by tools other than the shell, *e.g.* `login` itself, or your desktop manager (with the help of PAM and various other tools).

The *purpose* of a login shell isn’t to handle login, it’s to behave appropriately as the first shell in a login session: mainly, that means processing startup files which should only be processed once per login session, and protecting the login session from unwanted interaction with certain system features (job suspension in particular).

The specifics of a login shell, at least [as implemented in Bash](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/), are as follows:

- a login shell processes commands from `/etc/profile`, then the first file it finds among `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` (unless it’s a non-interactive login shell started *without* the `--login` option);
- exiting a login shell runs `logout` instead of `exit`;
- exiting a login shell hangs up all jobs;
- a login shell can’t be suspended;
- a login shell sets the `HOME` variable (except in POSIXly-correct mode);
- a login shell sets the `login_shell` shell option.

Comment: Thanks. 1. The first bullet point only applies to login shells which are started with `--login` option. Remember `BASH_ENV`? 2. I was wondering where I can also find "the specifics of a login shell"? I don't find it in the bash manual.

Comment: 1. No, it applies to all interactive login shells. Are you still talking about non-interactive login shells? 2. I read the Bash source code.

Comment: 1. right. I was more focused on login shells vs nonlogin shells. So was trying to see the intended purpose of login shells, which might be interactive or not. 2. Do you have a link? It is nice to have one, although I am yet able to understand.

Comment: You’ll find the source code [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/); look for `login_shell` to find all the login-shell-specific handling.

Comment: Thanks.  "a login shell processes commands from /etc/profile, then the first file it finds among ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile". If I am correct, a noninteractive login shell not started with `--login` option doesn't read and execute " ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile".

Comment: What happens if one runs `exit` instead of `logout`? Calling `exit` from a login shell started with `$ bash --login` from a parent non-login shell seems to appropriately return to the non-login parent shell... \[EDIT: Ah, [Kiwy's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/435967/136276) seems to explain it: there is no logout at all there. Logging out would mean to completely leave the linux session, right?]

Comment: @TheQuark in both cases, a login shell will exit as though `logout` had been used. In `bash`, that means executing `~/.bash_logout` if it exists. Any other behaviour depends on the program which started the shell.

Answer (score 3):

You already answer yourself your question.

> when I run `bash --login` to create a bash login shell, I don't have to log in

It means that you are already logged in and already have an environment that allows you to start application with your user rights.
Happily you don't have to type your password each time you start an application once you logged in.
The main difference is that with option `-l` or `--login` :

> [bash] first attempts to read and execute commands from /etc/profile and ~/.profile, in that order.

(extract from `man bash`).

The purpose would be to benefit from `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`. `bash` is a shell, not the component that handles a user session. `PAM` is the linux component that is responsible to identify you with your login/password.